# Angular2 routing configuration (route with two parameters)

Tags: angular

I'm configuring my routes on my angular2 application:

So, on `app.routes.ts`:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'app',   loadChildren: () => System.import('./layout/layout.module')
  }, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, {
    path: 'validate/:id/:token', loadChildren: () => System.import('./validate/validate.module')
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

Currently, I'm facing up with two problems:

1. When I go to `http://localhost:3000`, it's redirected to `http://localhost:3000/Living%20User%20Platform#/login`: I don't quite to figure out why this `Living%20User%20Platform#` is added to url, instead of `http://localhost:3000/login`.
2. As you can see I'm setting a route with two parameters: `validate/:id/:token`. Nevertheless, when I'm writting this url (http://localhost:3001/Living%20User%20Platform#/validate?id=sdfsdf&token=sdfsdf) on browser, it goes to error route:

`ValidateModule.ts`:

```
export const routes = [
  {path: '', component: Validate, pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Components / Directives/ Pipes
    Validate
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export default class ValidateModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `Living%20User%20Platform` into your route because may be you have not set correct `<base href="/">` in your HTML and for URL `validate/:id/:token` you need to check with UTL`http://localhost:3001/Living%20User%20Platform#/validate/sdfsdf/sdfsdf`

Comment: Thanks @ranakrunal9 . I've got it. According to last issue (route with parameters) is there some way to set a route path in order to accept an url with query parameters instead of `"path"` parameters like `validate?id=x&token=t`?

Comment: You can use `NavigationExtras` to pass params as `queryParams` while redirecting from one component to another. You can directly send params as query Params without declaring it into routing configuration and in component you need to use `ActivatedRoute` to get `queryParams` from url. check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @ranakrunal9. I'm facing up with other problem now: When I go to `http://localhost:3000/validate?id=i&token=t`, validate `component+template` are shown, nevertheless, I've detected on browser url goes to `http://localhost:3000/login`. I've added on post the module code where I define child routes (only `''`). Is something wrong?

Comment: I've also detected that `ValidateComponent.ngOnInit` is reached twice...

Comment: i think `pathMatch: 'full'` not needed in route inside `ValidateModule.ts`

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my routes (`validate/:id/:token` by simply `validate` path):

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'app',   loadChildren: () => System.import('./layout/layout.module')
  }, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, {
    path: 'validate', loadChildren: () => System.import('./validate/validate.module')
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

In order get query parameters from component using `ActivatedRoute`:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UsersService)
  {
    this.user = undefined;
  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'] || undefined;
      this.token = params['token'] || undefined;
    });
  }
```